# Does PHP interpreter eliminate dead conditionals?

Tags: php, php-internals

Before converting PHP source code to opcode, is there any optimization process that eliminates dead conditionals?

Example:

```
<?php

if (false) {
  echo 'false';
}
echo 'true';
```

Is it transformed to just `echo 'true';`?

If the answer is Yes, which of the following situations can PHP handle?

```
if(false);               //Explicit boolean
$true = true; if($true); //Variable that was assigned a constant boolean
if(ClassName::Constant); //Class constant
if(1>2);                 //Constant value expression
```

If there are version specific differences, please be generous.

Comment: to be fair php does indeed try to optimize code at runtime

Comment: The big issue for optimization is that variables are `typed dynamically` so can hold completely different things at different times (and often do). Making it difficult to optimize.

Comment: yeah just want to say that php try to optimize code, but on a way smaller task

Comment: PHP's OpCache can optimise at the bytecode level, but optimising the PHP code itself is up to the developer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, unreachable blocks will be eliminated by the "block pass" part of the opcache optimizer. For your particular examples:

```
if(false);               // 1. Will be optimized
$true = true; if($true); // 2. Will NOT be optimized
if(ClassName::Constant); // 3. Will MAYBE be optimized
if(1>2);                 // 4. Will be optimized
```

Example 2 will not be optimized, because we do not currently perform constant propagation on "real" variables. Currently the optimizer does not use SSA form and as such we do not have the confidence to perform this type of optimization. Once we have that, we can cover this using an SCP / SCCP pass.

Example 3 may be optimized, depending on where `ClassName` was defined. Generally, if it's either `self` in a non-rebindable scope or a class defined in the same file, it will be optimized. Furthermore the value of the constant must also be statically evaluable constant expression.

The unreachable code elimination is implemented as part of [block_pass.c](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_MASTER/ext/opcache/Optimizer/block_pass.c).

Comment: Example 3 (wrong number ;-)) will be optimized in case opcache is not loaded in every case the class is loaded before the constant usage. Also, it's not same file, but either self or the class name is referring to the class being currently defined.

Comment: @bwoebi I do not believe we remove unreachable blocks if opcache is not loaded. And opcache should also replace class constants in the same file, even if it's not the current class (unlike the constant folding in the compiler).

Comment: Thanks, they keyword "block pass" helped me to find the relevant source code, I updated your answer and included a link to the source file so everybody can benefit from it

Answer (score 0):

Simply No, It doesn't eliminate any code.